# React refs in memory game

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm a beginner in ReactJS and I'm making a memory game with it and have problems with revealing tiles.
I wanted to have a few values in parent component's state, like firstPick, secondPick, pickCount and also isHidden (this toggles icon visibility). 
But putting it in parent component makes click on any button toggle icon on every tile. To solve this, I moved isHidden property to Button (child) component. Now i wanted to manipulate state of Button from its parent component, so I found information about using refs somewhere in the internet. But using them makes clicking every button only toggle the last button in the container. I suppose i messed up something.
So my Button components looks like this:

```js
class Button extends Component {
  state = {isHidden: true};

  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden});
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="tile" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          <i
            className={this.props.icon}
            style={
              this.state.isHidden ? { display: "none" } : { display: "block" }
            }
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and my Board components looks like this:

```js
class Board extends Component {
  state = { firstPick: "", secondPick: "", pickCount: 0 };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonElement = React.createRef();
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.buttonElement.current.toggleHidden();
    this.setState({
      firstPick: this.icon,
      pickCount: this.state.pickCount + 1
    });
    alert(this.state.firstPick);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row align-items-start">
            <div className="col-3">
              <Button
                ref={this.buttonElement}
                icon={animalArray[0]}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              />
```

Of course there are 11 other Button components here, but they look just the same. (Btw is there a way to not repeat this code? They are placed in bootstrap container).
I also have 1 bonus question. Is there a way to set the state.firstPick to the icon property? I don't know how to refer to this value from the Parent component method. I tried writing this.icon, but i don't think it works. I wanted to keep two choices in state variables and then compare them. Or is there maybe a better way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Similar thing is taught by react in [tic tac toe game](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). You can just write map function to iterate over all buttons and don't need to use ref, having react handle the state would be good.

Comment: nah, they have 3x3 this.renderSquare() method called anyway

Comment: I meant how to lift state to parent component and use state instead of ref. Link was just for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just handle the toggle in the button itself?

```
class Button extends Component {
  state = {isHidden: true};

  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden});
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.toggleHidden();
    if (this.props.onClick) {
       this.props.onClick();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="tile" onClick={this.onClick}>
          <i
            className={this.props.icon}
            style={
              this.state.isHidden ? { display: "none" } : { display: "block" }
            }
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:** To preserve unique reference for `firstPick`, you can wrap your `handleClick` in another function:

```
handleClick = (icon) => () => {
  this.buttonElement.current.toggleHidden();
  this.setState({
    firstPick: icon,
    pickCount: this.state.pickCount + 1
  });
  alert(this.state.firstPick);
};

render() {
  return (
    <div className="board">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row align-items-start">
          <div className="col-3">
            <Button
              ref={this.buttonElement}
              icon={animalArray[0]}
              onClick={this.handleClick(animalArray[0])}
            />
```

`handleClick` now becomes a function that returns your original function (with some extra/unique context, in this case `animalArray[0]`).

Comment: because onClick event already is assigned to this.props.onClick, and i heard it's not possible or isn't a good practice to have onClick assigned to two event handlers.

Comment: @OskarNawara what if you want to hide a div, make two api calls and make another div visible?
would you not have onclick as a method of bundled onclicks in that case?

Comment: Have you tried it? This code is definitely possible. And it's not assigned to two handlers, its assigned to one which then propagates to the parent. Nothing wrong with this pattern.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk i just tried it and got TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleHidden' of undefined

Comment: @OskarNawara Ah right. Convert your onClick to an arrow function to preserve lexical this. (See update)

Comment: Doing this, he still would not be able to change a buttons state from the parent.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound Why should he need to in this case?

Comment: Because i needed to link it to this.props.onClick, as i wanted to change the state of Parent component

Comment: actually i don't understand this part: if (this.props.onClick) {
      this.props.onClick();
    }

Comment: @OskarNawara That's the other way around, and that line of code accomplishes it. It calls the parent's onClick passed down as a prop.

Comment: so it's the same as writing <Button onClick={this.props.onClick} /> ? Why do I need this if()? Also do you know how can i set state.firstPick to a property of <Button />?

Comment: No, it filters the call through your button's own onClick, which then calls the parent's (`this.props.onClick`). The if() is just to avoid null reference errors in case the prop is ever omitted from the parent. For your second question, see my update.

Comment: Now it seems to only store 2 previous picks, instead of current ones. So when i console.log() 4 first icons it's empty,empty,cat,dog for example. How can I fix this?

Comment: in React chrome addon it seems to change properly tho, so it's some kind of a problem with console.logging and alerting

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the complexity of your project is enough to warrant a store like flux or redux to keep track of all your button properties. This is generally the solution to complex relationships between parent and child elements.

In my opinion, refs should only be used for uncontrolled components, that is, any elements on your page that are not in react.

Comment: Ok, then I'll probably add Redux to it. Thank you for your advice

Comment: This isn't in the same **dimension** of the level of complexity to warrant redux.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk if there really is a need for the parent component to change the state of it's children, I would say it is.